# Passing array arguments to Perl subroutine

Tags: arrays, perl, subroutine

I am new to perl programming and I am trying to build a script using several subroutines on it. For a start I am trying to run a short mocke script to work out subroutines behaviour, but I don't get to understand the input.

Here is my code:

```
sub prueba{
  my (@array1, @array2)=@_;
  if (scalar(@array1)<scalar(@array2)) {
    print @array1,"\n";
  } elsif (scalar(@array1)>scalar(@array2)){
    print @array2,"\n";
  }
};

my @primero=(1,5,9);
my @segundo=(1,7,8,9,6,5,6,9);

prueba(@primero,@segundo);
```

I am passing two arrays and I want the subroutine to retrieve the answer according to those arrays, but when I run it I get no output, not even warning errors messages... I already tried using the refference to the array, but still not working:

```
sub prueba{
  my (@array1, @array2)=@_;
  if (scalar(@array1)<scalar(@array2)) {
    print @array1,"\n";
  } elsif (scalar(@array1)>scalar(@array2)){
    print @array2,"\n";
  }
};

my @primero=(1,5,9);
my @segundo=(1,7,8,9,6,5,6,9);

prueba(\@primero,\@segundo);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't pass arrays to subs (and they can't return them). You can only pass a number of scalars. What you are doing is equivalent to the following:

```perl
prueba(1,5,9,1,7,8,9,6,5,6,9);
```

All of the arguments end up in `@array1`. What we do is pass references to arrays.

```perl
prueba(\@primero,\@segundo);
```

But that also requires changing the sub. Without change, all of the arguments still end up in `@array1`. See [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) for a start on working with references. You can use

```perl
sub prueba{
  my ($array1, $array2)=@_;
  if (scalar(@$array1)<scalar(@$array2)) {
    print "@$array1\n";
  } elsif (scalar(@$array1)>scalar(@$array2)){
    print "@$array2\n";
  }
}
```

or just

```perl
sub prueba {
  my ($array1, $array2) = @_;
  if    (@$array1 < @$array2) { say "@$array1"; }
  elsif (@$array1 > @$array2) { say "@$array2"; }
}
```

`<` and `>` expect a number, so they already impose scalar context. And might as well use `say`, though that requires `use feature qw( say );` (or something like `use 5.014;` which does the trick as well).

Comment: I see you've unaccepted the answer. Is there an issue with this answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [prototypes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Prototypes) to make it *look* like you're passing multiple arrays, and have perl turn them automatically into references:

```perl
sub prueba :prototype(\@\@) {
    my ($array1, $array2) = @_;
    if (@$array1 < @$array2) {
        print @$array1,"\n";
    } elsif (@$array1 > @$array2){
        print @$array2,"\n";
    }
}

my @primero=(1,5,9);
my @segundo=(1,7,8,9,6,5,6,9);
prueba(@primero, @segundo);
```

But read the documentation carefully to understand the cases where the subroutine can be called without enforcing the prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all I just figured out what I wanted. I found that I can actually pass an array to perl, however maybe I am not explaning mysfel properly.The thing is to load the arrays as follow, inside the subroutine.

```
my @primero=@{$_[0]};
my @segundo=@{$_[1]};
```

This means we are using the reference. Ehen running the function, we must write the \ before each input:

```
prueba(\@primero,\@segundo);
```